# Dimissing DialogFragment but objects are still in memory

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have an `Activity` and there I have a `MenuItem`, which when clicked, initializes the following `DialogFragment`:

```
MapDialogFragment df = new MapDialogFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDoubleArray("lat_log", new double[] {48.85139, 2.34798});
df.setArguments(bundle);
df.show(fragmentManager, "google_maps_dialog_fragment");
```

This DialogFragment has a GoogleMaps as `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in it.

The `GoogleMap` object has a `OnMapClickListener` that when the user clicks on it, adds a Marker to it. All works great.

Then, user clicks on close button and I run the following code:

```
getArguments().remove("lat_log");
dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

The `Dialog` is then closed and my `Activity` code is refreshed with the data entered by the user (via a `Listener`).

When the user clicks on the `MenuItem` again and the `Dialog` opens, every data inserted by the user previously is still there.

The Dialog's code has been initialized in the `onCreateView()` method. I have not implemented `onResume()`, if it helps to know...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much,
Felipe

**EDIT 1:**

```
I have tried the following before showing the DialogFragment:
Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("google_maps_dialog_fragment");
if(prev != null) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(prev).commit();
}
MapDialogFragment df = new MapDialogFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDoubleArray("lat_log", new double[] {48.85139, 2.34798});
df.setArguments(bundle);
df.show(fragmentManager, "google_maps_dialog_fragment");
```

Didn't work as well...

Anyone with ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
Found the source of the issue:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
            System.out.println("this is not working");
        }
....
```

I have added the `if (view != null)` because for some crazy reason, when I instantiate the DialogFragment for the second time, the inflate method returns null... I don't know why. So I am keeping a reference to the `view` as class variable... 
So now I have to find out why the inflate is returning now...

**EDIT 4**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null) 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
```

There you go. This works!

Comment: how do you that the object is  retained?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I believed that running `getArguments().remove("lat_log");` would suffice to remove the data.

Comment: what does "objects are still in memory" mean?

Comment: What about `dismiss()` instead of `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`?

Comment: @blackbelt means that when opening the Dialog for the second time, I can see all the Markers that the user inserted in the first time. I want a fresh, clean Google Maps.

Comment: @TronicZomB, I tried that too and no luck! Thanks.